# How can I find where was my website hosted

Tags: dns, hosting

Ok it may sound strange, but I forgot where is one of my websites hosted.

I remember the domain name and I have access to setup the DNS server, but I don't remember the nameserver. It was something like ns113.icndns.net but I checked and the domain is not there.
When I use that tool I see my domain name listed there: https://viewdns.info/reverseip/?host=nemo.icnhost.net&t=1
But what are the dns server names? Is there an easy way to find or am I missing something general knowledge? Please help.

p.s. I don'g have access to the hosting account and the guy having it will return at the end of the week, but it is too late.

Answer (score 2):

Some website do the job for you, such as https://who.is
it will give informations regarding a specific url.

You can also use command whois from nslookup tools to resolve those kinds of problems
https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/whois/

cheers

Comment: whois is showing my current domain setup, but the website is hosted in other company and I don't know which nameserver to use. I can't setup the DNS server correct value. this answer sadly does not help a lot :(